# How can we retrieve words without case sensitive using python group by?

Tags: python

```
things=[("red",1),("red",2),("green",5),("green",10),("red",15)]
for key,value in groupby(things,lambda x:x[0]):
    for thi in value:
        if(b==key):
            print("things present in:",thi[1])
```

Comment: Note that from the above code if I try to retrieve "red" or "RED" it should show the same output for red...Please help me at your earliest!!

Comment: Simply add .lower() (or upper) to both b and key, then you will not have to care about the case anymore

Comment: @ Dr Mouse Sir  thank you so much!! it worked!!

Answer (score 1):

Just add `casefold` to your strings.

```
things=[("red",1),("red",2),("green",5),("green",10),("red",15)]
for key,value in groupby(things,lambda x:x[0]):
    for thi in value:
        if b.casefold() == key.casefold():
            print("things present in: ", thi[1])
```